# Dynamic update form

Tags: webforms, forms

I used `$form` to hold a list of checkbox options which are created programmatically.
I would like to add additional checkbox from an "add" submit button after the form is rendered by the theme.

My question is where I add the additional item to? `$form` array or `$form_state` array?
I got confused because I am using drupal 7 and I should use `$form_state['rebuild']`.
If I add the additional item to `$form_state`, how the theme to refresh and render the new list. The theme is using render form.

Thank you.

Comment: Post your initial code for better comprehension :)